# Character encoding issues for semigraphics

Tags: character-encoding, putty

[Spark](https://github.com/holman/spark) outputs bars of varying heights, depending on numerical input. The `x-factor` is provided as parameter. For example:

```
spark 0 30 55 80 33 150
▁▂▃▅▂▇
```

But when using PuTTY, this is what I am seeing for some different ways of encoding:

[image]

I was wondering how to make the characters show up properly.
I can't seem to figure out the right encoding.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Spark outputs bars of varying heights, depending on numerical input.  The x-factor in Spark is that it is all in text.

For example:  

    `spark 0 30 55 80 33 150
    ▁▂▃▅▂▇`

Comment: ok thanks.  I couldn't add it as a tag without more stackoverflow reputation but I added it to the title.

Comment: Does the font you use contain all those characters? Because this looks like a font issue.

Comment: Ok that'd be great if that's the issue.  Is there a font that emulates the gnome-terminal font that I could use in Putty (Windows)?

Comment: The default font for gnome-terminal is DejaVuSansMono. You can get it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dejavu/files/dejavu/2.34/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.34.zip/download